# Loading a CSS file when opening a tab with a local URL

Tags: javascript, css, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am opening a tab that loads a local HTML file from an addon (using addon-sdk) like this:

```
tabs.open({
  url: self.data.url('index.html'),
  onReady: myScript
});
```

But I don't see a way to load a CSS stylesheet that goes along with the HTML file. I would expect to not have to write inline styles.

Am I missing something? Surely there is a way to load the CSS using the API.

Comment: CSS files are generally linked from _within_ the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in `<head></head>` section of `index.html` to include your css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your_css_file.css">
```

Comment: I'll be damned, that worked. I tried that first, obviously, but it didn't work and I thought that the addon-sdk was doing something special under the hood, perhaps some kind of sandboxing.